# Python Argparse Odd Behavior

Tags: python, namespaces, argparse, attributeerror

Getting an odd error after I added a new argument `epsilon`:

```
parser.add_argument('--epsilon', '-x', default=0.3)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.epsilon
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'epsilon'
```

But when I moved this file outside of my project folder, it prints the expected value `0.3`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Does your project has any file named *args.py* or some other object with name `args`? Try `print args, type(args)` to see what you got.

Comment: `type(args)` gives `<class 'argparse.Namespace'>` `args` gives `Namespace(epsilon=0.3)`

Comment: Can you show all the code needed to reproduce this problem with just a copy/paste?  So, please include the line where you instantiate the `parser`.  Because if I just put `import argparse; parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()` before your code I get no error.

Comment: Do you have a file called `argparse.py`?